# Select option form not work in master slider?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My demo at here: http://project.bulleno.com/dwi/index2.html

In my demo, the select option of other form work well, but the select of form on slider not work and I cannot figure out and solve it.

I think it is conflict with jquery from master slider and smart form. But I cannot troubleshoot it. So I need help and any help is greatly appreciated. You can check my code below:

```
<div class="ms-slide slide-1" data-delay="9">
    <div class="slide-pattern"></div>
    <img src="js/masterslider/blank.gif" data-src="images/slide3.jpg" alt="" />
    <h3 class="ms-layer text31 text-center"
        style="top: 230px; right: 230px;"
        data-type="text"
        data-delay="500"
        data-ease="easeOutExpo"
        data-duration="1230"
        data-effect="top(250)">Welcome To DidYouBlow</h3>
    <h3 class="ms-layer text36 text-center"
        style="top: 20px; right: -900px;"
        data-type="text"
        data-delay="0"
        data-ease="easeOutExpo"
        data-duration="1230"
        data-effect="top(250)">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 bmargin">
            <span class="visible-lg">
                <div class="feature-box57 bmargin">
                    <br />
                    <font color="000000"><i class="fa fa-university"></i><font size="+2">Submit DWI INFO</font><i class="fa fa-university"></i></font>

                    <form method="post" action="send.php" id="">
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                        <br>
                        <div class="col-sm-5">
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="Name" placeholder="Full Name">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-5">
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="Name" placeholder="Phone Number">
                        </div>
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                        <br>
                        <div class="col-sm-5">
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="Name" placeholder="Email">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-5">
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="Name" placeholder="City / Court">
                        </div>
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                        <br>
                        <div class="col-sm-5">
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="Name" placeholder="Name">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-5">
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="Name" placeholder="Name">
                        </div>
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                        <br>
                        <div class="col-sm-5">
                            <label for="month" class="field select">
                                <select id="month" name="month">
                                    <option value="">How Did You Hear About Us?</option>
                                    <option value="Facebook">Facebook</option>
                                    <option value="Google">Google</option>
                                    <option value="Yahoo">Yahoo</option>
                                    <option value="Mailer">Mailer</option>
                                    <option value="Radio">Radio</option>
                                    <option value="Bing">Bing</option>
                                    <option value="Referral">Referral</option>
                                </select>
                                <i class="arrow double"></i>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-5">
                            <label for="month" class="field select">
                                <select id="month" name="month">
                                    <option value="">How Did You Hear About Us?</option>
                                    <option value="Facebook">Facebook</option>
                                    <option value="Google">Google</option>
                                    <option value="Yahoo">Yahoo</option>
                                    <option value="Mailer">Mailer</option>
                                    <option value="Radio">Radio</option>
                                    <option value="Bing">Bing</option>
                                    <option value="Referral">Referral</option>
                                </select>
                                <i class="arrow double"></i>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                        <br>
                        <div class="col-sm-11">
                            <textarea class="form-control" id="sendermessage" name="sendermessage" placeholder="Enter message"></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                        <br>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-dark-2 less-round less-padding">Submit Information</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </span>
    </h3>
</div>
```

Comment: In the console it says `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).percentcircle is not a function` at line 113 of functions.js

Comment: I tried deactivate this script and nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

The problem cause this matter is: mouse and loop option in master slider.

I had disable both options and everything work well.